# ¿Cómo puedo hacer este código más eficiente/corto que funcione de la misma manera?

Tags: javascript, nodejs

Tengo el siguiente enlace para que puedan ver el código:

Me gustaría hacer el código más eficiente:

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/AntonioVladimir/3jwbqg70/6/)

También intento que la secuencia empiece desde 0 y no con elementos inicializados como los lista o elementos < li >.

Comment: Hola, por favor agrega el código pertinente dentro de la pregunta. Así es mas facil y rápido ver lo que necesitas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El hecho de que quieras que la lista inicie vacía es una "limitante" para que el código sea más corto pues tienes que hacer algunas validaciones para evitar errores.

```js
function nuevoNumeroFibonacci() {
    const ul = document.getElementById('serie');
    const serie = Array.prototype.slice.call(ul.getElementsByTagName('li'), 0);
    let nuevoElemento;
    if (serie.length === 0) nuevoElemento = 0;
    if (serie.length === 1) nuevoElemento = 1;
    if (serie.length > 1) nuevoElemento = parseInt(serie.pop().innerHTML) + parseInt(serie.pop().innerHTML);
    const newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = nuevoElemento;
    ul.appendChild(newLi);
}
```

```css
* {
  font-family   : 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
}

.title {
  font-family   : 'Roboto Condensed', sans-serif;
  text-align    : center;
  line-height   : 40px;
  color         : rgb(0, 0, 0);
  font-weight   : 200;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.div-padre {
  display: block;
  text-align    : center;
}

ul {
  text-align: left;
  display:inline-block;
}

li {
  list-style:none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 2%;
  width: 2%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
    color           : #fff;
    font-weight     : light;
    background-color: #6b81ff;
    width           : 100px;
    font-size       : 1em;
    box-shadow      : 0px 0px 2px 1px black;
    border          : none;
    display         : block;
    margin-left     : auto;
    margin-right    : auto;
    outline: none;
}
```

```html
<h1 class="title"> FIBONACCI </h1>
<button onclick="nuevoNumeroFibonacci()">Siguiente</button>
<div class="div-padre">
    <ul id="serie"></ul>
</div>
```

Otra opción para evitar "reconstruir" la serie ya generada pero no más corta aunque pienso que es igual o mejor legible, es separar el cálculo de la serie:

```
let elemento = 0;
const serie = [0, 1];

function nuevoNumeroFibonacci(){
    const ul = document.getElementById('serie');
    const newLi = document.createElement('li');
    newLi.innerHTML = series(elemento);
    ul.appendChild(newLi);
    elemento ++;
}

function series(n) {
  if(n === 0) return serie[n];
  if(n === 1) return serie[n];
  serie.push(serie[n-1] + serie[n-2]);
  return serie[n];
}
```

Nota también que he agregado un id al `ul` para no hacer tan genérica su búsqueda.